# Applet not initialized but compiles need help in creating a pokemon map

Tags: java, swing, grid, applet, paint

Hey guys i wanted some help with a pokemon game that I am making for a final project. I wanted to create a map that paints images to the screen based on a random variable. The class compiles but when I run the applet in applet viewer it says "Start: applet not initialized" I have no idea what's wrong.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Image.*;

class map extends JApplet
{
    Image grass;
    Image Sgrass;
    Image sand;
    Image[][] gr = new Image[10][10];
    public void init()
    {
        grass = getImage(getCodeBase(),"Grass.jpg");
        Sgrass = getImage(getCodeBase(),"Non-Grass.jpg");
        sand = getImage(getCodeBase(),"Sand.jpg");
        grid();
    }
    public void grid()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
            {
                double x = Math.random();
                if(x<=0.70)
                {
                    gr[i][j] = grass;
                }
                else if(x>0.70 && x<=0.90)
                {
                    gr[i][j] = Sgrass;
                }
                else if (x>0.90)
                {
                    gr[i][j] = sand;
                }
            }
        }
    }  
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        while(b<=500)
        {
            while(a<=500)
            {
                for(int z = 0; z<10; z++)
                {
                    for(int w = 0; w<10; w++)
                    {
                        g.drawImage(gr[z][w],a,b,50,50,this);
                        a+=50;                    
                    }
                }
            }
            b+=50;
            a = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: I just wanted to test if the pictures would paint to the screen. Im not finished with the class yet...

Comment: I mean: Have you made the HTML file that loads the applet and how does it look? How do you call the appletviewer?

Comment: `Start: applet not initialized` Why? It gives details, what are those details? Copy/paste them..

Answer (score 2):

The only problem i can see with your code is your class is not public and until it is public (it will have default access) other classes in another package can not access it. For example while running it the class `sun.applet.AppletPanel` will not be able to access it.

So change your class declaration to

```
public class map extends JApplet {
```